Transaction batching Fails with "Execution Failed during simulation"
I am trying to batch transactions using Safe4337Pack with passkey. The transaction seems to work fine with transactions less than five but mostly fails with 5 transactions.
The error usually occurs at the point of calling the "createTransaction"
const safeCreatedTx = await safeErc4337Pack.createTransaction({
    transactions: safeUserOps,
  
  })


Full error Log below;
URL: https://api.pimlico.io/v1/polygon/rpc?apikey=API_KEY
Request body: {"method":"eth_estimateUserOperationGas","params":[{"sender":"0x33c031751e0bAa63934fda673E14EA0C17fc04c1","nonce":"0x8","initCode":"0x","callData":"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","callGasLimit":"0x1","verificationGasLimit":"0x1","preVerificationGas":"0x1","maxFeePerGas":"0x9eca5e240","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x9eca5e240","paymasterAndData":"0x","signature":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000094a4F6affBd8975951142c3999aEAB7ecee555c200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001e00000000__SIGNATURE___000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},"0x5FF137D4b0FDCD49DcA30c7CF57E578a026d2789"]}

Details: UserOperation reverted during simulation with reason: 0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010457865637574696f6e206661696c656400000000000000000000000000000000
Version: viem@2.21.54


Have you tried using Pimlico's dashboard for debugging the transactions that fail and get more information on them?
